# Determine whether this statement is true or false

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have a statement

**A**: "$\forall x, \exists y$ such that  $\forall z, x + y = z$."

I can find a $y$ for all $x$ and $z$ such that $y = z -x$.

But this $y$ is not fixed for all $x$ and $z$.

Hence **A** is $false$.

Can you verify?

Comment: Your conclusion is right -- but note that for the statement to be true, $y$ wouldn't need to be "fixed for all $x$ and $z$" -- it is allowed for $y$ to depend on $x$ but not on $z$.

Comment: Also, the words "such that" have no use when you're writing the quantifiers symbolically. You can either write "There is an $z$ such that $P(z)$ holds" or "$\exists z\,P(z)$", but don't start mixing words into a symbolic formula!

Comment: It is false since you can take $z=x+y+1$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm "it is allowed for y to depend on x but not on z". Can you explain why.